# how to develop tvOS app using nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to build a tvOS and roku app with nativescript.

I was about to start working on the tvOS app after I read this article https://www.nativescript.org/blog/running-the-nativescript-runtime-for-ios-on-apple-tv but I'm not sure where the nativescript ios runtime or the metadata generator are in my project. Also, would this mean that my provisioning file and certificates should be for an appletv app instead of ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS runtime is generally downloaded from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-ios) for your project. But it includes support for only iOS. For tvOS, you will have to checkout the [open source iOS runtime project from Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/) and update the [config scripts](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L41-L42) as described in the blog post,

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos;-iphonesimulator;-appletvos;-appletvsimulator")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS "iphoneos iphonesimulator appletvos appletvsimulator")
```

and build your custom version of iOS runtime with [CMake](https://cmake.org/).

Comment: hey thanks for helping me through that. I'm trying to build this on windows and it was my understanding that I should be able to develop ios apps with nativescript through nativescript sidekick. Do you have any experience with this because I've been fighting through this for a while

Comment: You can build iOS applications only on Mac. NativeScript CLI / Sidekick has a feature Cloud Builds, to helps windows users. Basically the code is uploaded to their server, built there and the binaries are shipped back to your machine.